# run bump in the wire scenario in kubernetes pod

Tags: linux, kubernetes, iptables

We are trying to implement something like bump in the wire sceario with the kubernetes pod running as bump.

so basically we have traffic for a paticular destination we intercept the traffic in kubernetes pod and throw it again towards destination .

To run this scenario we started of with **squid proxy** which would redirect the outgoing traffic to kubernetes pod(bump) and once inside pod we would run iptables rule to redirect the processed packets again to destination ip.

**The iptables rule used : iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3124 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.1.1.1**

however this iptable rule does not work(also i need the returning traffic to be redirected to original destination ie after getting processed in pod)

so say destination is 172.172.172.172(some ip outside the cluster) squid has been setup to redirect this destination traffic to service which has node port enabled(hence new destination is minionip:nodeport). when the traffic reaches the pod.. after processing the data outgoing traffic has to be set to original destination(172.172.172.172) instead of going back

I cant seem to find a way. is there any iptable rule to do so taking in consideration of kubertes setup iptables rules.

also is there any other elegant way to do so.
please help.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? You are using Squid proxy to move traffic to pod and then this traffic redirect to something inside the cluster? If so did you consider to use [Nginx Ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/). If no please elaborate and provide scenario.

Comment: so say destination is 172.172.172.172(some ip outside the cluster) squid has been setup to redirect this destination traffic to service which has node port enabled(hence new destination is minionip:nodeport). when the traffic reaches the pod.. after processing the data outgoing traffic has to be set to original destination(172.172.172.172) instead of going back.